# Работа с циклами javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть ситуация:
поля на странице с именами типа field[]
генерятся автоматом, количество заранее неизвестно. Нужно пройтись по всем полям с именами field[] и проверить не пустые ли они...
В php все просто реализуется, а вот в javascript я как ни мучался, не смог понять что к чему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0, il = els.length; i < il; ++i){
    if(els[i].name == 'field[]'){
        /*
        делаем что-то с els[i]
        если поля могут называться field[1], field[42] и т.п, то
        if(/field\[\d*\]/.test(els[i].name))
        */
    }
}
```

**Обновлено.**

```
<script>
function testForm(x){
    var els = x.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i = 0, il = els.length; i < il; ++i){
        if(els[i].name == 'field[]'){
            if(els[i].value == ''){
                alert('Заполните поле!');
                els[i].focus()
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
</script>

<form onsubmit="return testForm(this);">
    <input name="field[]">
    <input name="field[]">
    <input name="field[]">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: а что такое test?

Comment: RegExp.[test][1](String) - функция, возвращающая, соответствует ли регулярка строке.

[1]:http://javascript.ru/RegExp/test

Comment: не работает, ошибок не выдает.

Comment: Если ошибок не выдает, значит работает. =) Только им надо уметь пользоваться. Обновил сообщение.

Comment: да есть, спасибо.

Comment: Если не против, запишу к себе на блог :) у меня там склад )

Comment: Не, не против). Но вот код "как есть" вы выложили зря - я опустил многие параметры, и HTML-код невалидный. Мне просто нужно было показать механизм работы.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так

```
<form name="form">
<input name="fild" value="Не пустое"></input>
<input name="fild1" value=""></input>
</form>

<script>
var els = document.getElementsByTagName ('input');
// Перебираем все поля ввода
for(var i = 0;i < els.length; i++){
var ist = els[i];
//Выводим сообщение о наличии данных
alert(ist.value);
//Если пустое значение
if(ist.value=='')
{
//Сообщим наименование этого поля
    alert('Пустое поле '+ist.name);
    }

}
```

Comment: не совсем подходит. Мне нужно проверять четко текстовые поля с конкретными именами - field[], Ваш пример, в принципе работает, но проверяет все - даже submit'ы

Answer (score 2):

Может будет достаточно написать

```
<input name="fild" value="Не пустое" required></input>
```

а броузер уже пускай сам проверяет пустое или нет ?

Comment: А если браузер не умеет проверять?

Comment: хром, сафари, фф, опера умеет. Насчет ie не вкурсе. но ie-9 точно должен поддерживать, возможно даже ie8

Comment: Увы, не все браузеры поддерживают это свойство, а только [некоторые новые][1].
[1]:http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/required

Comment: IE 7 проверял - ему пофиг, он все пускает.

Comment: да.. ie как всегда в своём репертуаре ...